# Writing the output to a text file

Tags: java, io

I would like to write the following output in to text file. I know it is easy but i think i forget some basics here.

I tried using 'BufferedWriter' but I cant find the variable output to pass to the writer. Can anyone help?

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.Writer;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;


/**
 * Example program to list links from a URL.
 */
public class SimpleWebCrawler {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 0, "usage: supply url to fetch");

        String url = "http://www.placeofjo.blogspot.com/";
        print("Fetching %s...", url);


        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");


        System.out.println("\n");


        for (Element link : links) {

            print("  %s  ", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));


        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }


}
```

Comment: "enter code here"? Is the preview that hard to use?

Comment: "I tried using buffered reader" - buffered reader is for file input not for file output. `BufferedWriter` would have made sense.

Comment: sorry, i not used to this forum.. ringbearer : yeah..you got me..the question has typo errors..it supposed to be bufferedwriter..sorry..

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code to be like this:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/path/to/file/name.txt")));
for (Element link : links) {
   bw.write("Link: " link.text().trim());
   bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```

Comment: the bw.write(<your message string>) refers to what ?

sorry my coding quite poor.

Comment: For example:
   bw.write("Link: " + link.text().trim());

Comment: thanks..i got it..however the in the output i got is the links stick to each other..i mean like

 Link:http://www.twitter.com/jozefinfin/Link:http://www.facebook.com/jozefinfin/

i would like to it become 

Link: http://www.twitter.com/jozefinfin/


Link: http://www.facebook.com/jozefinfin/


like an array of links..thanks

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need is here : http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/WriteToFile.html

```
try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename"));
    out.write("aString");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Why would you swallow the exception?!? You should also flush the *buffered* writer

Comment: close() automatically flush the writer, and since I don't know what he wants to do when an exception arise, I can't write the code for him...

Answer (score 0):

Check out `java.io.FileWriter`